# What happens if the invoker don't have the table used in the plsql procedure when using authID as current_user?

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, invoke, authid

Suppose I've created a procedure in plsql with authid current_user to update a table t1. What happens if another user invokes the procedure if the table t1 is not created for user2.

Will it cause an error or update the user 1 table?

Comment: This may be tested by yourself, why do you ask?

Answer (score 2):

`AUTHID` sets the user whose *privileges* are in effect. It does *not* set the current *schema*. Therefore it will have no effect on object resolution. The procedure owner will be the current schema, and any unqualified object references that procedures makes will resolve to objects owned by the procedure owner (or public), regardless of who the invoker is. But with `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`, whether or not it is allowed to *act* on those objects depends on the privileges of the invoker.

Answer (score 1):

When executing a PL/SQL procedure with the AUTHID CURRENT_USER clause, it means that the procedure runs with the privileges of the current user invoking it. If the invoking user does not have the necessary privileges or access to a table referenced within the procedure, it will result in an error.

Its may happened in two different scenario

1. Runtime error
2. Compilation error

you may refer this https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_authid_current_user.htm